# Browser Back shows escaped characters in <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html, escaping, back-button

I have a textarea input where I enter some text and proceed to the next page.
After moving onto the next page, if I press browser BACK, the text in the textarea comes back with escaped characters:

```
F&G asdg
```

becomes

```
F%26G%20asdg
```

Input code:

```
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="12" placeholder="enter description here:" required></textarea>
```

I use js to manipulate the data and the description string gets escaped before it gets sent to the next page where it gets unescaped for further processing.

Not really able to post the rest of the code on the page, but was wondering if anyone has experienced something like this before and can point me in the right direction.